# Crashes and ANRs not visible in Play console

Tags: android, google-play-console

Whenever I go to the "Crashes and ANRs" page, all I see is the title "Monitor crashes and application not responding (ANR) errors in your app" and a "Learn More" button. The rest of the page is blank. It has been more than two weeks since we posted the app for testing, and I know that testers have experienced crashes. Why can't I see them?